# Bash shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

Recently I started working with shell scripting in Linux (newbie). I wanted to know the commands or the procedure to change from one folder to another within the loop? I mean how can I call different folders inside the executing loop? Presently, I'm renaming all the folders with no's say 1,2,3..... and using these inside the loop. I know this is not a good way to use scripting.

```
set k=1
while ( $k <= 17)

## initial path set
    cd /home/naren/Documents/BASELINE_INSP/FreeSurfer/$k/RSFC
```

Each time 'k' updates, move to different folders since I named all folders as no's.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to write your code without numeration, 
you can use `ls` command which lists the files in the current directory or use `ls [folder_name]` to list the files in a folder,
In order to assign the result to file use $ operator 
**Edit:** 
 since `ls` has some [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) as [@randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir) mentioned it is better to use iteration as following:

```html
for f in ./* do
  //do something with $f
done
```

Comment: You should **never** do [that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Yeah you are right it seems the right way is something like that 

`for file in somepath/*; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    some command "$file"
done`

according to 
[link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i <= 17; i++)); do
    #Changing folder inside the loop
    cd "/home/naren/Documents/BASELINE_INSP/FreeSurfer/${i}/RSFC"
    #Here you can execute something more if you want
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#
# Start with ID equal to zero and increment
#
ID=0

#
# then use a say a while loop
#
while [ ${ID} -lt 5 ]; do 
    echo "my dir is /here/${ID}/there"; 
    ((ID++)); 
done
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer requires an explanation of how/why this code helps.

Comment: I wouldn't write hybrid `bash`/POSIX code like this. The `while` loop is the correct method in POSIX, but then you must use something like `ID=$((ID + 1))` to increment the variable. If you *can* use `((...))`, then you could also more easily use a C-style `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean how can I call different folders inside the executing loop?

Preferably, if you want to loop for all folders matching a certain pattern (which needn't contain numbers), just specify the pattern in a `for` loop:

```
for folder in /home/naren/Documents/BASELINE_INSP/FreeSurfer/*/RSFC
do  cd "$folder"
    # do something there
done
```